# Grails - Replace a dropdown list with a controller rendered g.select

Tags: jquery, ajax, grails

I have these domain classes:

```
class Client {
    String name
    Date birthDate
    BigInteger accountNumber
    ...
}

class PaymentCondition {
    Client client

    String conditionName
    BigDecimal discountPercentage
    ...
}

class Payment {
    Client client
    PaymentCondition paymentCondition

    BigDecimal grossIncome
    BigDecimal totalDiscount
    BigDecimal netIncome
    ...
}
```

For these classes there are their automatically generated controllers and views. When I want to register a Payment I have to select a Client or enter the Client's account number (this input field is implementing the JQuery UI autocomplete feature, so a list with all occurrences according the entered digits is shown) and through an AJAX call retrieve its data. The problem is that the PaymentCondition drop-down list must be updated or replaced with a list containing the payment conditions related to the selected client.

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: take a look at ajaxdependancyselection plugin, it also provides custom g.select calls within tag lib so if you wanted to learn on how to use it...

Answer (score 0):

In your controller (called via AJAX), create a method to handle the AJAX post. Note that the parameter name `number` will need to match the name of the parameter in the second argument of the `$.post` call later on:

```
def updateAccountNumber(String number) {
    render text: g.select(id: 'accountNumberSelect', name: 'accountNumber', from: Account.findAllByNumber(number), optionKey: "id", optionValue: "someProperty")
}
```

In the GSP, add some javascript to attach a listener to one of your drop downs:

```
<r:script>
$("#clientSelect").change(function() {
    var clientNumber = $(this).val();
    $.post("${g.createLink(action: 'updateAccountNumber')}", {number: clientNumber}, function(result) {
        $("#accountNumberSelect").replaceWith(result);
    }); 
});
</r:script>
```

Comment: I know how to render a drop-down list using the g.select tag from my controller. The problem is that I don't know how to replace the former with the generated one.